# Remove newline if preceded with specific character on non-consecutive lines

Tags: bash, unix, sed, replace

I have a text file with every other line ending with a % character. I want to find the pattern "% + newline" and replace it with "%". In other words, I want to delete the newline character right after the % and not the other newline characters.

For example, I want to change the following:

```
abcabcabcabc%
123456789123
abcabcabcabc%
123456789123
```

to

```
abcabcabcabc%123456789123
abcabcabcabc%123456789123
```

I've tried the following sed command, to no avail.

```
sed 's/%\n/%/g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Try `sed '/%$/{N;s/%\n/%/}' file > output`. If there are no consecutive lines ending with `%` this should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data sample imply that there are no several consecutive lines ending with `%`.

In that case, you may use

```
sed '/%$/{N;s/\n//}' file.txt > output.txt
```

It works as follows:

- `/%$/` - finds all lines ending with `%`
- `{N;s/\n//}` - a block:

  - `N` - adds a newline to the pattern space, then appends the next line of input to the pattern space
  - `s/\n//` - removes a newline in the current pattern space.

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/kev4ZQ).

Comment: Couldn't you just `s/\n//`? It's not like there are multiple newlines to pick from.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, true, just a habit to triple-sure of everything when it comes to regex.

Answer (score 4):

By default sed can't remove newlines because it reads one newline-separated line at a time.

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box for any number of lines ending in `%`, consecutive or not:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/%$/ ? "" : ORS)}' file
abcabcabcabc%123456789123
abcabcabcabc%123456789123
```

and with consecutive `%` lines:

```
$ cat file
now is the%
winter of%
our%
discontent

$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/%$/ ? "" : ORS)}' file
now is the%winter of%our%discontent
```

Answer (score 0):

In portable sed that supports any number of continued lines:

*parse.sed*

```
:a                # A goto label named 'a'
/%$/ {            # When the last line ends in '%'
  N               # Append the next line
  s/\n//          # Remove new-line
  ta              # If new-line was replaced goto label 'a'
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -f parse.sed infile
```

Output when *infile* contains your input and the input from Ed Morton's answer:

```
abcabcabcabc%123456789123         
abcabcabcabc%123456789123
now is the%winter of%our%discontent
```